# Speed and frequency of a transverse wave traveling through a string made of different materials

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, frequency, speed

Say a wave generated by an oscillation machine is traveling through a string.

Will the frequency of the wave be the same across the string if:

1. The string is made up of 2 different materials with the same dimension
2. The string is made up of 2 strings with the same material but different dimension

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this page in the site help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more on what topics you can ask about here.

Comment: Related : [Why does medium not affect the frequency of sound?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/193609)